# Count products with custom metadata field in an order

Tags: plugin-development, loop, get-post

I have a wordpress plugin which performs a count of purchased products in an order which are flagged with my custom metadata value.
The custom metadata value is in the form of a checkbox within the product page. I'm using WooCommerce/WooCommerce subscriptions.

If a customer purchases 5 products, a count is done and then stored in a variable. Only products that have the custom metadata value checkbox are counted.

The count does not occur, as I believe my custom metadata value checkbox is not being detected when using `get_meta();` within the loop.

**Code below shows the metadata checkbox**

```
/* Adding Extra field to product to Enable Traccar integration */

// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wootraccar_product_custom_fields_add');
function wootraccar_product_custom_fields_add(){
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="wootraccar_product_custom_field">';

    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
        'id'        => '_wootraccar_integration',
        'desc'      => __('Check this box if Traccar integration is required for this product', 'woocommerce'),
        'label'     => __('Traccar Integration Required', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'  => 'true'
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wootraccar_product_custom_fields_save');
function wootraccar_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $wootraccar_integration = isset( $_POST['_wootraccar_integration'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wootraccar_integration', esc_attr( $wootraccar_integration ));
}
```

**the for each loop**

```
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $email  = $order->get_billing_email();
        $name = $order->get_billing_first_name();

        $devicecount =0;

            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            if( $item->get_meta( '_wootraccar_integration', true )=='yes')
            {
                $devicecount = $devicecount +  $item->get_quantity();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    $userid="";
    $integration_status="";
      // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $email  = $order->get_billing_email();
        $name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $items = $order->get_items();

        $devicecount =0;        

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_name = $item->get_name();
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $product_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();

            $productToBeIntegrated=get_post_meta($product_id,'_wootraccar_integration', true);
            //$integration_status.=$productToBeIntegrated;

            if ($productToBeIntegrated=="yes") {
                $devicecount = $devicecount +  $item->get_quantity();
                $integration_status.=$devicecount;          }
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear how this solves the users problem. Could you [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/397008/edit) and add in more detail on what this code does and how it solves the users  problem?